# Issues with scope and OOP in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop

I've been playing around with reactJS and JS with the Spotify API lately and I've run into some issues, when I try to call one function from another I get the error this is not defined, referring to the keyword this. I'm not too familiar with OOP in JS so I've figured its something to do with that or the scope, but I cant figure out how to fix it.
I've attached the code below taken from my app.js.

```
getPlaylistTracks(tracksURL) {
    spotifyApi.getPlaylist(tracksURL).then(
      function (data) {
        console.log(data);
      },
      function (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    );
  }

  getPlaylists() {
    spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists().then(
        function (data) {
          var playlistArray = [];
          for(let i = 0; i < data.items.length; i++) {
            var tracksURL = data.items[i].tracks.href.slice(37,59);
            var playlist = new PlaylistObj(data.items[i].name, data.items[i].tracks.total, tracksURL);
            this.getPlaylistTracks(tracksURL);
            playlistArray[i] = playlist;

          }
          return playlistArray;
        },
        function (err) {
          console.error(err);
        }
    );
  }
```

The function is called in the render() and the error message I have been getting is.
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): this is undefined

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript functions defined using the `function` keyword lose the value of `this`. There are multiple ways to fix this issue like using an intermediate variable or using [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Function/bind) but the global accepted solution is to use [ES6 arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead.

```js
getPlaylists() {
  spotifyApi.getUserPlaylists().then(data => {
    // ...
  },
  err => {
    console.error(err);
  });
}
```

Arrow functions are one of the most powerful and well-known features added in ECMAScript 2015 so I believe you should check out some articles like [this one](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/06/es6-in-depth-arrow-functions/).